# Linux : Alternative of install_name_tool of MAC in CentOS

Tags: linux, mysql, patchelf

I am looking for alternative of install_name_tool of MAC in CentOS. Exactly I want to build MySQL on non default location. Also the shared libraries of the mysql binary should be on non default location and properly linked.

I wasnt able to link shared libraries libssl & libcrypto to the mysqld binary.

```
[user@localhost mysql]$ ldd /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld
        linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00186000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x008e2000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0x0097f000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0x00912000)
        libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00c70000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00727000)
        libssl.so.1.0.0 => not found
        libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => not found
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00a7e000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x008b0000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00a70000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00755000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00731000)
```

I am sure that openssl is installed in /usr/local/extra directory as i also installed apache perfectly, which is currently working, my configure command is  :

```
cmake . -LH -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/extra/include -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/extra/lib -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/mysql -DMYSQL_DATADIR=/usr/local/var -DSYSCONFDIR=/usr/local/mysql/etc -DMYSQL_UNIX_ADDR=/usr/local/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock -DCURSES_LIBRARY=/usr/local/extra/lib/libncurses.so.5 -DCURSES_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/extra/include -DWITH_SSL=yes -DWITH_ZLIB=system
```

While configuring it also shows :

```
-- checking for module 'openssl'
--   found openssl, version 0.9.8e-rhel5
-- Found OpenSSL: /usr/local/extra/lib/libssl.so;/usr/local/extra/lib/libcrypto.so (found version "1..")
```

Can any one suggest me a tool to link shared libraries to the binary.

Comment: Linux paths are so f**k'd up. After 30+ years they still cannot get it right. RPATHs, SONAMEs, and now some Elf TAGS. Why the hell don't they make the common case "just work"? It appears to be a classic problem of allowing engineers to drive requirements. The engineers took a 1% case and displaced a 95% case. The 1% case should be doing something special, not the common case. Its classic engineering failures. Thank god they are not designing automobiles and airplanes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [PatchELF](http://nixos.org/patchelf.html) utility might be useful. Otherwise, see the `ldconfig` man page, and the file: `/etc/ld.so.conf`

Comment: Hi. Thanks, adding path to ld.so.conf worked. But it was affecting my PC in some way which I couldn't recognize. Like my gedit stopped working after that, etc. Also this fix would work only for my PC. I want to use same binaries on other machine. There I wont be able to edit the ld.so.conf file. I will try PathELF now, but is there any other way to fix this ? Thanks a tonne.

Comment: PatchELF is exactly what i needed. Again thanks a tonne.